# Android - Saving location updates (using LocationServices API) from a Service

Tags: android, service, location, broadcastreceiver, google-maps-android-api-2

I have set up an environment where the app receives location updates, which is handle on the `onLocationChanged` callback.

```
// Setup the client.
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
}

// Register the location update.
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

// Interface callback. Called every 5 seconds.
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // Save the location coordinates to a file.
}
```

So far so good. Then, for my purposes, I saw the need of triggering the `onLocationChanged` callback  even if the app is not running - that's where BroadcastReceivers and Services come in.

I want a BroadcastReceiver to start a Service, that would save the location coordinates updates do a file. So, in my mind, the architecture would go something like:

```
// Register the BroadcasReceiver to the activity.
registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter());

// The BroadcastReceiver
public static class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        MyActivity.myContext.startService(new Intent(context, MyService.class));
    }
}

// The Service class.
public static class MyService extends Service {
    private boolean isRunning  = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {        
        isRunning = true;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        //Creating new thread for my service.
        //Always write your long running tasks in a separate thread, to avoid ANR
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                    // Save location updates.
                }
                //Stop service once it finishes its task
                stopSelf();
            }
        }).start();
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        isRunning = false;
    }
}
```

All LocationServices API setup process (the first block of code below) is inside the activity `onCreate` method.

**So, how can I receive location updates from the tread's `run()` method created by the Service, if the app is not running?** The whole design is to be like that:

```
App not running/destroyed > A specific action trigger the Broadcasreceiver > The BroadcastReceiver trigger the Service > The Service trigger the location updates and save it to a file.
```

Comment: The broadcast receiver needs to be implemented outside activity. Then register it in the manifest instead. This way the service can be awaken even if app is not running.

Comment: Good observation. Thanks.