# How is Toast is displayed by a Service - Android

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, toast

So I have a registered a BroadcastReceiver to my app, that once triggered will start a Service.

The Service class methods display a Toast when they are called, which after tests are indeed being displayed.

But if the app **is not running/was destroyed**, how is possible the Toast is being displayed if the context passed into the `Toast.makeText(Context context, CharSequence text, int duration)` is a context that was never instantiated?

I mean, the app is not running/is destroyed, so the context variable was never initialized.

**The main activity:**

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    MyBroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new MyBroadcastReceiver();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Some code here.

        // Instantiate the context.
        context = MapsActivity.this;

        registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter());

    }
}
```

**The BroadcastReceiver**

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            MapsActivity.context.startService(new Intent(context, MyService.class));
        }
    }
}
```

**The Service**

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.context, "Service onCreate", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    // Some other super methods.
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Is your toast displayed and you don't know why? is your toast not displayed but you'd like it to be? Something else?

Comment: My Toast is displayed, and I don't don't why, because the context passed to the argument is null?

Comment: is it? is the context null? how did you test that?

Comment: hint: if the broadcast was received, then it was registered, then your context was indeed initialized. if your app had been completely terminated, you wouldn't receive the broadcast. However, it is true that having a static context is a very bad idea. Since Service is also a Context, use that instead of the context of your activity.

Comment: I didn't actually. But how come the context isn't null? Do the service call the activity onCreate at any time? I'm just trying to undertstand so I can see the logic behind it.

Comment: @njzk thanks for your comments. If you have some time I'd be glad to hear your comments at this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31838342/android-saving-location-updates-using-locationservices-api-from-a-service?noredirect=1#comment51599881_31838342

Answer (score 1):

This works because your `Context` is saved in a static field, which's lifecycle is as long as the one of the process. And a running service keeps a process active.

However this is **a bad design**! You should not keep a reference on a context in this way, especially if you don't need to:

A `Service` itself implements `Context`, so you can replace `MapsActivity.context` with `this`. Of course the same applies to the `BroadcastReceiver`: Use the parameter `context` instead of `MapsActivity.context`.

Comment: You can access context from Service and BroadcastReceiver both.

Comment: @Saurabh You're right, I included that in the answer.